# 403 when downloading S3 signed HTTPS URL with Postman or Python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I'm writing a tool that has to download files from S3 buckets, using presigned URLs (which I receive from customers, I don't create them myself). By which I mean URLs like the following: https://customer-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/file.txt?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJXUV54IKCQRZ6AKQ/20220217/eu-west-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220217T114356Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=e257fd0f315cb7351ef4bcb125bdc81de6f4e0d01c50f2c956efae20ee0768b1

When I access those URLs with wget / curl or in the browser, all is well.

But when I try to get the same URLs through Postman or Python.requests, I get a 403 error.
I've try setting similar headers (user-agent primarily) as the browser, but without success.

Here is my very simple code:

```
import requests
payload={}
headers = {
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Connection": "keep-alive"}
response = requests.request("HEAD", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print(response.text)
```

but each time I get a `response.status_code` of 403

Comment: Presigned links are signed for specific actions.  The link you have is signed for a "GET", not "HEAD"

Comment: Wow, they go that far in their fine-tuning of permissions?  May I ask how you determined that from just looking at the URL?

Comment: I can't tell looking at the URL, but the fact that the signature includes the HTTP action as part of the input, and it working in the browser means it must be for a GET request, in addition to GET presigned URLs being by far the most common ones.